# Display multiple anchor links within a single div container

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display multiple anchor links within the same div container...specifically pdf files. I'm fairly new to jQuery and was hoping there'd be a way to do it.

Comment: This is not even a question. You don't even have a single question mark. Is there a way to do what in jQuery? How do you want the links displayed? What's wrong with just putting `<a../>` elements inside your ,`<div.../>`. Write a meaningful question, get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dear fidel, your question doenst make any sense!

I´ll reply to your title,

> display multiple anchor links within
>   same div container

It is very simple, you do like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

This has nothing to do with PDFs or jQuery!

Good luck!! and if you want me to clarify please explain more and better :)